# How can I trade specific Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I saw how to randomly trade two Pokémon (known as wonder trade) or trade Pokémon with a specific or random player (known as link trade).

But how can I trade in such a way I give a specific Pokémon and get a specific other one, as it was possible in Pokémon X and Y, and in Sun and Moon (known as GTS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [January 28th 2020](https://press.pokemon.com/POKEMON-HOME-TO-LAUNCH-IN-FEBRUARY-2020), it has been officially confirmed that Pokémon Home will feature the Global Trade System.

Pokémon Home will feature a free version and premium version. Through the GTS, the free version will allow you trade up to 1 Pokémon at once time while the premium version will allow you to trade up 3 Pokémon at once.

---

The Global Trading System (GTS) did not make its return in Sword and Shield, so trading in this manner is not a native feature in these games.

As an alternative, you could always join a Reddit or Discord group that could be used as a mock-GTS. A friend of mine is apart of a Discord group where he can request specific Pokémon with IV spread, moves, etc...  and somebody will hook him up with one using the link trade feature.